# Object Swinging

Tags: objects, transforms

This is a very beginner question, but I don't know how to word it.

Let's say that I have a cube a distance away from my pivot and I set a key frame. Then, I move a couple frames and then rotate the cube around the pivot and set another key frame.

Obviously, the cube will move in the shortest path-a straight line-to the next key frame. How would I make it so that cube moves in the swinging/circular motion that I saw when I manually rotated it around the pivot?

Thanks in advanced.

[image]

Comment: Maybe I was showing too much of a broad of an example. I'm trying to make a rubik's cube to rotate one side, but each individual cube moves in the shortest possible path instead of the natural curve.

Comment: As you are starting with blender, you need to spend some time learning the different forms of **interpolation** in the graph editor, and how those can help you control the speed and trajectory of transformation.

Comment: I get how that can change the speed, but how do you make it control the trajectory?

Comment: If you change the handles for movement in X and Y Axis on the graph editor you can control the trajectory while keeping the same coordinates and time for the existing keyframes

Answer (score 1):

You can add an Empty object at the location of your cursor, parent the cube to it, then annimate the rotation of the Empty :

Shift+A / Empty / Plain axes (or what looks better to you, it's just visual).

Select the Cube, keep shift pressed, then select the Empty, and hit Ctrl+P. In the menu select Object.

Now if you rotate the Empty, the cube will follow.

Comment: Ok, but I'm making a rubik's cube so I would have to change the parents everytime I want to rotate a different side.

Comment: @caleblee Rubik's cube is a bit complex. Read through these links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=rubik